# PnP with .NET Core

Tags: csom, pnp

I can see CSOM now supports .NET core. I just tried making a small sample Azure Function App but it fails with:

> "Could not load type
> 'System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager' from assembly
> 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'."

Does PnP still not support .NET Core or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It depends which build of PnP Core you are using. For modern .NET versions, you should use the .NET 5.0 build:

https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore#will-this-work-in-modern-net